# Capturing a row's ID to use as a table's name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Just to save anyone reading this time and trouble, DO NOT use this method to store surveys. As pointed out in the answer, this is incredibly poor programming (not to mention dangerous to kitties)**

Forgive me if this question is somewhat convoluted. I'm working on building a program that allows users to create surveys and post them for users to take.

Long story short, I have a table that looks like this:

```
**survey_info**

id          bigint(20)     Auto_increment     Primary Key
title       varchar(255)
category    bigint(20)
active      tinyint(1)
length      int(11)
redirect    text
```

now, when a survey is created, a new table is also created that is custom built to hold hte input for that survey. The naming schema I'm using for these new tables is survey_{survey_id}

What I'm hoping to do is in the list of surveys, put the number of responses to a survey to the right of it.

Alright, now my actual question is this, is there a way to retrieve the number of rows in the collection table (survey_id) within the same query I'm using to gather the list of available surveys? I realize that I can do this easily by just using a second query for each survey and grab it's rowcount, but my fear is that the larger the number of surveys the user has, the more time-consuming this process will become. So is there any way to do something like:

```
SELECT s.id AS id, s.title AS title, c.title AS ctitle, s.active AS active, s.length AS length, s.redirect AS redirect, n.num FROM survey_info s, survey_category c, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM survey_s.id) n WHERE s.category = c.id;
```

I just don't know for sure how to use the s.id as part of the other table's name (or if it can even be done)
Any help, or even a point in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: **On no!** Every time an id used to name a table, there dies a kitten!

Comment: Please, save kittens. Don't create a new table for each survey.

Comment: This is the definition of a SQL anti-pattern.  Any design which involves creating new tables like this is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Okay, well in that case, what would you suggest that I use to reference this new table to it's parent survey's information?..

Comment: Please for the love of all that is holy learn about relational table design and entity models. "one to many" or "has many" is the key feature you need to focus on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a relational model that will store all surveys options in one table. This is a sample design:

```
survey
------
id PK
title

surveyOption
--------------
id PK
survey_id FK
option

surveyResponse
--------------
id PK
surveyOptionId FK
response
```

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, this would have each question linked to the survey, and each answer linked to the question it answers (which could then be linked back to it's parent survey)?

Comment: @SamHuckaby Correct. This model goes `survey > surveyOption > surveyResponse`

Comment: Okay, I understand that. That actually would be much simpler. thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @SamHuckaby It is critical that you understand the concept of this model. Please do some research on relational design.

Comment: I will. I've actually been using this design for the rest of the survey, just not for the answers. I guess the light just hadn't come on yet. Up till now I've had Survey > element(question) > question_options(if multi-choice) and survey > category

Answer (score 3):

You need to use one table for all the surveys.
Add newly created id not as a table name but as a survey id in that table.

Comment: But each of the surveys has a different number of questions, and questions of varying information types...

Comment: @SamHuckaby That's where a relational model comes in. You do know what that is, no?

Comment: @njk Actually, I'm not terribly familiar with them, would you recommend somewhere to read up on them?

Comment: @SamHuckaby I recommend you [read this book](http://www.amazon.com/Database-Design-Mere-Mortals-Relational/dp/0201752840/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1359742112&sr=8-1&keywords=database+design+for+mere+mortals) before going any further.

Comment: @SamHuckaby that's easy. A table with surveys, a table with questions, a table with answers, a table with results. Every matter in it's table, identified by surveys id.